# How do you avoid the nav bar being cut off everytime you resize the browser window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, header

i have a fixed header, in the header,  the logo and height change as you scroll, everything is working, except when you resize the browser window, everything remains in place but the nav bar is cutted. Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

The nav bar and the logo image changes using Jquery, i'm using width:100%; on header and the nav bar width:700px; the logo is float:left and nav bar is float:right.

half of the header disappears when i resize the window.
what i want is the header to show all when the browser window is resized.

```js
 $(function() {
   var shrinkHeader = 100;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
     if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
       $('.head').addClass('shrink');
       $('#logo').hide();
       $('#postLogo').addClass('now').show();
     } else {
       $('.head').removeClass('shrink');
       $('#logo').show();
       $('#postLogo').addClass('now').hide();
     }
   });

   function getCurrentScroll() {
     return window.pageYOffset;
   }
 });
```

```css
.head {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1350px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu_list {
  width: 655px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <img/>
    </div>
    <div id="postLogo" style="display:none">
      <img/>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="menu_list">
        <li>1</a></li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end menu-->
  </div>
```

Comment: Kindly show some code

Comment: Please share some code, how you are doing things and what view type you are using?

Comment: i want this to work on all resolutions and the header is just getting cut off instead of just stay there and as you scroll horizontally you get the part that is being cutted but no, its just cutted of...

Answer (score 0):

Provides your "nav" means your `#memu_list` - *please be more clear in your question* - you have to set it with an relative width (e.g. in `%` or `em`)

Comment: i have tried that didn't worked! when i use min-width it only affects below the header and when i resize the window half of the header don't appear!

Comment: Don't know what you mean.  Please give more details. And simplfy your example. And use the same ids and names in your code, you're using here in your questions. E.g. "Nav" Tell us, what you to expect from your code.